# antd checkbox inside a button

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript

react beginner here, here i have antd checkbox, i want to change this checkbox into a button but still have checkbox functionality: here is my checkbox:

```html
  import { Checkbox } from "antd";

 <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                  <Checkbox
                    indeterminate={indeterminate}
                    onChange={onCheckAllChange}
                    checked={checkAll}
                  >
                    Select All{" "}
                  </Checkbox>
                </div>
```

this is what i tried to do, i tried to give opacity zero to checkbox to hide it and then put checkbox inside a button in order to change the look of it to button and have checkbox functionality, but problem is, this new button is working if you click on the left side of the button but right side is not working, any solution ?
:

```html
  import { Checkbox } from "antd";

 <div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
                  <button>
                    <Checkbox
                      style={{ opacity: "0" }}
                      indeterminate={indeterminate}
                      onChange={onCheckAllChange}
                      checked={checkAll}
                    >
                      Select All{" "}
                    </Checkbox>
                    Select All
                  </button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to do exactly what the checkbox does, simply pass the `onCheckAllChange` to the button  `onClick`.

```
<div className="modal-body d-flex flex-column">
 <button onClick={onCheckAllChange}>
   Select All
 </button>
</div>
```

and your handle change is something like this assuming your state variables are
`checkedList`, `indeterminate`, and `checkAll`:

```
const onCheckAllChange = (e: any) => {
 setCheckedList(!checkedList.length ? allColumnKeys : []);
 setIndeterminate(false); 
 setCheckAll(!checkAll);
};
```

Comment: like that it would just work one way, it will uncheck everything, but clicking again will do nothing

Comment: so like this it was easy to implement it, thanks, but what if it wasnt this easy to convert checkbox into a button, do you have somewhere some example i could learn of ?

Comment: It depends on the scenario you are facing, in this situation it was clear, but sometimes it isn't. For example in the case of the handler executes differently based on the HTML element (button, or checkbox, ...etc). In this situation, you can pass a  parameter(type of the element) to the handler and take actions based on that type.

Comment: i'm not pro, wanna learn, do you know somewhere an example like this 'you can pass a parameter(type of the element) to the handler and take actions based on that type' ?

Comment: Im not a pro too :D. Reducers in react are perfect example[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).